# Why can't I put a hash inside itself as a key?

Tags: ruby

I can use hashes as keys and values:

```
a = {}
b = {}
a[b] = b
a          #=> {{}=>{}}
a[b] == b  #=> true
```

I can even put a hash inside itself as a value:

```
a[:a] = a
a          #=> {{}=>{}, :a=>{...}}
a == a[:a] #=> true
```

But I can't put a hash inside itself as a key:

```
a[a] = a
a          #=> {{}=>{}, {...}=>{...}}
a[a]       #=> nil
a[a] == a  #=> false
```

I would expect `a == a[a] #=> true` in this case.

Why does this happen? I don't have a use case for this, I'm just curious about why a hash can't be used as it's own key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not that you cannot. You just need to rehash after you modify a mutable key in the hash.

```
a = {}
b = {}
a[b] = b
a[:a] = a
a[a] = a

a.rehash
# => {{}=>{}, :a=>{...}, {...}=>{...}}
a[a] == a
# => true
```

The `a` is different before and after `a[a] = a`. So you needed to update the `a` key of `a`.

Comment: ...which is why it's usually a very bad idea to use something as mutable as a hash as a key.  Anyone with a reference to it can change it, and there is no guarantee that he/she will know to rehash it, or bother to do so.